# creating a nested json document

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have below document in mongodb.

[image]

I am using below python code to save it in `.json` file.

```
file = 'employee'
json_cur = find_document(file)
count_document = emp_collection.count_documents({})

with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
     f.write('[')
     for i, document in enumerate(json_cur, 1):
         print("document : ", document)
         f.write(dumps(document))
         if i != count_document:
              f.write(',')
     f.write(']')
```

the output is -

```
{

    "_id":{
        "$oid":"611288c262c5c14df84f649b"
    },
    "Lname":"Borg",
    "Fname":"James",
    "Dname":"Headquarters",
    "Projects":"[{"HOURS": 5.0, "PNAME": "Reorganization", "PNUMBER": 20}]"

}
```

[image]

**But i need it like this** (Projects value without quotes) -

```
{

    "_id":{
        "$oid":"611288c262c5c14df84f649b"
    },
    "Lname":"Borg",
    "Fname":"James",
    "Dname":"Headquarters",
    "Projects":[{"HOURS": 5.0, "PNAME": "Reorganization", "PNUMBER": 20}]

}
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the JSON from the Projects field

Like this:

```
from json import loads
document['Projects'] = loads(document['Projects'])
```

So,

```
file = 'employee'
json_cur = find_document(file)
count_document = emp_collection.count_documents({})

with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
     f.write('[')
     for i, document in enumerate(json_cur, 1):
         document['Projects'] = loads(document['Projects'])
         print("document : ", document)
         f.write(dumps(document))
         if i != count_document:
              f.write(',')
     f.write(']')
```

Comment: after printing all the document, it gives error - `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType`. because sometimes projects is `None`. please help.

Comment: Solved!! Thanks.